# How assign user to group in ansible?

Tags: unix, ansible, chown

What module do I need to use of Ansible to perform this action?

`chown -R vmail:vmail /var/mail`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-manage-files-and-file-properties) module and make sure to set

```
  state: directory
```

, because `recurse: yes`

> *"Recursively set the specified file attributes on directory contents.
>   This **applies only when state is set to directory**."*

```
- file:
    state: directory
    path: /var/mail
    recurse: yes
    owner: vmail
    group: vmail
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the file module, more information on [Ansible file module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html)

The example from there :

```
- name: Recursively change ownership of a directory
  file:
    path: /etc/foo
    recurse: yes
    owner: foo
    group: foo
```